# recursion function to print all possible combinations

Tags: c, recursion

I have a string representing a number, with some digits "hidden" behind the symbol '!'.

I would like to generate and print all possible numbers obtained by replacing the '!' by '1' or '2'.

For instance:

```
INPUT:  12!21!
OUTPUT: 121211
        121212
        122211
        122212
```

I would like to solve this problem with a recursive function in C.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to StackOverflow. The question has been closed. I believe this is because it's really hard to understand the problem. Can you please edit the question to explain the problem in a little more detail? How do you go from input "12!21!" to output "121211" "121212" "122211" "122212"? If you explain the problem more clearly, we can vote to reopen the question.

Comment: Nevermind, I understood the problem and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me write this in pseudo-code:

```
void combination(input_array){
boolean bExclamation_found = (index("!",input_array)>-1);
if bExclamation_found
then printout(input_array)
else {
  combination(replace_one_exclamation(input_array, "1"));
  combination(replace_one_exclamation(input_array, "2"));
}
```

Good luck